# Mathematical justification for scalar product of infinitesimals

Tags: differential-forms, nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

**Setup**: Uniform circular motion under a central force.

**Claim**: Work done by a central force (say gravity) in 'keeping a particle in uniform circular motion' is zero.

**Reasoning for the claim**: At any point on circle, the force vector $\vec{F}$ is radially towards center, and the infinitesimal displacement vector $\vec{dl}$ is tangential to the circle, so the scalar product $ \vec{F}.\vec{dl}$ is zero.

**Questions**: What is the precise mathematical justification for:

1) Taking length of $\vec{dl}$ to be **zero**, when it comes to actual displacement along tangential direction (otherwise then for any finite displacement in straight line, particle will no longer be on circle. And also then there would be question whether $\vec{F}$ is perpendicular to the head or to the tail of the vector $\vec{dl}$)

2) Taking length of $\vec{dl}$ to be **non-zero**, when taking scalar product (as otherwise scalar product becomes $ \vec{F}.\vec{0} = 0$)

Comment: While this question might seem to be about mathematics, the line of thinking demonstrated here is much more common in physics. Perhaps asking the [physicists](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) would give you better odds at an explanation? I have voted to move the question there.

Comment: OP wants a precise mathematical justification, so I think the question is definitely on topic here. Mathematicians are the ones who care about mathematical rigor, not physicists.

Comment: Do you know line integral?

Comment: This is *Zeno's arrow paradox*. See here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes